# pi-frozen-in-termial

Tags: pi-3b+

I was in my terminal, sudo installing apache2, and I clicked out to pause a video real quick. When I clicked back on the terminal I have a white terminal screen with nothing anywhere. It then popped up that the terminal was not responding so I agreed to kill it. My screen and mouse are frozen but I am not sure about the keyboard. What should I do?

Comment: perhaps reboot?

Comment: "the terminal was not responding so I agreed to kill it" - with whom? In general, it's a bad idea to interrupt an installation process, if system libraries are being updated when you kill the upgrade you may end up with an unbootable system.

Comment: You could try the `REISUB`-routine, but **NOT** do the `UB` (which remounts all drives as readonly and reboots). To do so click  `ALT+SysRq` and then one letter of `REIS` after the other. With some luck you could then use `CRTL+ALT+F1` to get to a terminal prompt and finish the installation there before you reboot.

Comment: Is it possible that clicking out of the terminal to pause a video caused it to freeze? I don't want to make the same mistake. When the screen turned white, a notif popped up stating it was not responding wait or kill it...and that is when I agreed to kill it. I believe my keyboard was also frozen as I tried REISUB and I also tried to get to another backup terminal that I read about in this question ->https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28256/raspberry-pi-frozen. I also tried removing the mouse and keyboard, but nothing was working. It was as if the entire thing froze.

Comment: After running out of options I unplugged it. I was lucky and when I rebooted it everything was fine. I would love to know what I did to freeze it so I don't make the same mistake. I ended up restarting the process it previously froze on, in the terminal, and it worked like a charm.